# grep command to grep the gene list in first file present in the gff file

Tags: grep, bioinformatics

I am using this command to grep the gene list in first file present in the gff file.

```
grep  -w -f upregulated_genes_in_BEg GCA_900659725.1_ASM90065972v1_genomic.gff
```

it did not work for me.. please any suggestion.

Gene list in the first file..

```
LOCUS10095
LOCUS10108
LOCUS10129
LOCUS10130
LOCUS10152
LOCUS10161
LOCUS10225
LOCUS10252
LOCUS10266
LOCUS10268
LOCUS10294
LOCUS10313
LOCUS10351
LOCUS10355
LOCUS10358
```

Comment: Could you possibly also show some part of the GFF file that you are working with because we can only say that the search terms seem to not appear in the file right now, at least not as words (`-w`).

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add more details. Make clear which of the two files you show in the question, and also show the other file (or a short example). What exactly means "it did not work"? see [What Do You Mean "It Doesn't Work"?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147616/what-do-you-mean-it-doesnt-work)

Comment: here is the part of the gff file.. CAACVG010000001.1 EMBL region 1 15202 . + . ID=CAACVG010000001.1:1..15202;Dbxref=taxon:64391;gbkey=Src;mol_type=genomic DNA;note=contig: 10000|quiver
CAACVG010000001.1 EMBL gene 4526 9821 . - . ID=gene-CALMAC_LOCUS1;Name=CALMAC_LOCUS1;gbkey=Gene;gene_biotype=protein_coding;locus_tag=CALMAC_LOCUS1

Comment: @SherAfzalKhan please ***[EDIT]*** your question and include some relevant lines from the gff file. Also, since the people here are not bioinformaticians, explain that gff is a tab-separated format.

Comment: Make sure the example you give would provide output. It should have one of the gene names you are looking for.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Skip the `-w` flag to `grep`, since this limits the search to match at word boundaries **as defined by `grep`** (from the docs, *"Select only those lines containing matches that form  whole  words."*). This command produces the expected output:

```
cat > GCA_900659725.1_ASM90065972v1_genomic.gff <<EOF
CAACVG010000001.1 EMBL region 1 15202 . + . ID=CAACVG010000001.1:1..15202;Dbxref=taxon:64391;gbkey=Src;mol_type=genomic DNA;note=contig: 10000|quiver
CAACVG010000001.1 EMBL gene 4526 9821 . - . ID=gene-CALMAC_LOCUS1;Name=CALMAC_LOCUS1;gbkey=Gene;gene_biotype=protein_coding;locus_tag=CALMAC_LOCUS1
EOF

cat > upregulated_genes_in_BEg <<EOF
LOCUS1
LOCUS10095
EOF

grep -f upregulated_genes_in_BEg GCA_900659725.1_ASM90065972v1_genomic.gff
```

Prints:

```
CAACVG010000001.1 EMBL gene 4526 9821 . - . ID=gene-CALMAC_LOCUS1;Name=CALMAC_LOCUS1;gbkey=Gene;gene_biotype=protein_coding;locus_tag=CALMAC_LOCUS1
```

If you need a precise control over the word boundaries, perhaps this Perl one-liner is a better choice:

```
perl -lne 'BEGIN { @upregulated_genes_in_BEg = `cat upregulated_genes_in_BEg`; %is_upregulated_gene_in_BEg = map { $s = $_; chomp $s; ( $s => 1 ) } @upregulated_genes_in_BEg; } ( $gene ) = m{(LOCUS\w+)}; print if $is_upregulated_gene_in_BEg{ $gene };  ' GCA_900659725.1_ASM90065972v1_genomic.gff
```

The one-liner reads the contents of the file with upregulated genes into a hash. It then uses this hash to look up whether the hash has the `LOCUS...` word in the current line. If the hash has the word, the line is printed.

The Perl one-liner uses these command line flags:
`-e` : Tells Perl to look for code in-line, instead of in a file.
`-n` : Loop over the input one line at a time, assigning it to `$_` by default.
`-l` : Strip the input line separator (`"\n"` on *NIX by default) before executing the code in-line, and append it when printing.

**SEE ALSO:**
[`perldoc perlrun`: how to execute the Perl interpreter: command line switches](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html#Command-Switches)
[`perldoc perlre`: Perl regular expressions (regexes)](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html)
[`perldoc perlre`: Perl regular expressions (regexes): Quantifiers; Character Classes and other Special Escapes; Assertions; Capture groups](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Regular-Expressions)
[`perldoc perlrequick`: Perl regular expressions quick start](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrequick)